# NFS File Mounting error in centOS

Tags: linux, centos, mount, nfs

I'm trying to mount server filesystem using NFS in centos. But I'm getting **Connection timed out** error.
Below are the steps I followed.

**At server side:**

```
[centos@ip-172-31-46-199 landingzone]$ sudo vi /etc/exports
/home/user/landingzone 172.31.37.128(rw,sync,no_root_squash)

sudo exportfs -av <br> exporting 172.31.37.128:/home/user/landingzone
```

**At Client Side:**

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/NFS
[centos@ip-172-31-37-128 ~]$ cd /mnt 
[centos@ip-172-31-37-128 mnt]$ ls 
nfs  NFS  tecmint <br>[centos@ip-172-31-37-128 mnt]$ sudo mount 172.31.46.199:/home/user/landingzone /mnt/NFS
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

FYI, I started NFS service.

Comment: "/home/swathim/landingzone" != "/home/user/landingzone"... Although that should result in a "Permission denied", not a "Connection timed out". I suspect one or more daemon isn't running on your server.

Comment: is the service nfs started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum install nfs-utils nfs-utils-lib

chkconfig nfs on 

service rpcbind start

service nfs start
```

Client side:

```
chkconfig netfs on

sudo mount -t nfs 172.31.46.199:/home/user/landingzone /mnt/NFS
```